# oracle proxy authentication and nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I have an oracle database where I'm using proxy authentication and windows authentication. This allows me to authenticate the user against AD servers and yet allows pooled connections.

I understand that I can use the oracle data provider for dot net. However, I would prefer to use an orm such as nHibernate.  Is it possible to use the nHibernate and use oracle proxy authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All nhibernate needs to know is how to create a connection to your oracle databae right? This is all done by the connection string where you pass in the proxy user's name/pw or you could use `Integrated Security` in Oracle 8i release 3 or later.

This means this has nothing to do with nhibernate I would say. So yes, it should work.